# How to change spacing before and after \paragraph command?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I tried to control the spacing before `\paragraph{}` using a command such as

```
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
```

but that doesn't influence it. (It influences spacing between regular paragraphs).

How do I control the space before `\paragraph`?

Comment: As far as I know, `\parskip` and `\paragraph` are not connected. A `\paragraph` is a structuring command whereas `\parskip` is used for the paragraph skip, which is rather visually outstanding element

Comment: You shouldn't be using `\paragraph{}` to begin with. This is a sectioning command, not the marker for a paragraph start; just leave a blank line between paragraphs. And don't use vertical space between paragraphs, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As egreg stated in his comment, `\paragraph` should not be used to start a text paragraph, but only (if at all) to use the structuring level 'paragraph', which is already below `subsubsection`.

If there are `subsubsection` levels, it's ok (in some sense) to reduce the space, but this is a matter of taste.

I used the `\xpatchcmd` to replace the paragraph spacings

```
{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}
```

by

```
{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
```

Have a look on the screenshot!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}

\noindent Unpatched 

\paragraph{First}

\paragraph{Second}


\blindtext[1]


Now patching it... compare!

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\paragraph}{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}{\typeout{success!}}{\typeout{failure!}}
\makeatother

\paragraph{First}
\paragraph{Second}

\blindtext[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for `\paragraph` from `report.cls`.

Don't forget to use `\renewcommand` and also `\makeatletter \makeatother`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\makeatother
```

You can control the space changing the 2nd line.

Comment: Or patch the command ;-)

Comment: Or use  `\titlespacing` from the `titlesec` package.